# Drupal List View for data entry to multiple records

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to create a data entry form in Drupal 7 that is similar to Filemaker's List View. List View is a view that contains many records on a page. When Submit button is clicked, data entered in the fields will be assigned to the individual records.
For example, I have a list of students' names and a column field of grade type. The student's name will be created from Drupal View's filtering, but the grade field will be empty waiting for me to key in.
What is the proper Drupal's module that can enable this functionality? Or what can I do to create this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is closer to your original request, im testing this out now and I think it should more than do the trick, much more interestingly too.
http://drupal.org/project/slickgrid

**Edit:** 
I highly recommend trying this its awesome!!

**A couple quick tips**
Be sure to also install http://drupal.org/project/title so you can reset the title (make it a field), Basically with this editor you can only edit actual fields, so same goes for location module, you'll need to use the field option rather than node option.

One possible downer, at least for my site, it appears the drupal module does not support jquery 1.7 which my site uses, so a few buttons etc don't work as expected, also the drupal module does not support the latest slickgrid release either.  I'd like to look into fixing that but I dont have the time just yet, possibly someone will before long.  If jquery 1.7 is not required for your site then none of that will be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured how to do something similar, although I went about it a different way then I think would be the most desirable, at any rate what I did works perfectly for me at the moment.

**What I did...**
Used a google docs spreadsheet for data entry, exported a CSV file, then used Feeds module to Import and Map it to my desired content type.  I was even able to get location, taxonomy & image fields to map.

**Modules & Stuff Used...**

- *Feeds* http://drupal.org/project/feeds which also includes Feeds
  Importer, you'll want to read through all the instructions to be sure
  you understand the import methodology, I could never explain it all
  here!
- *Feeds Tamper* http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper , I used this to
  explode the cell which had a | separated | list of taxonomy terms (dont use comma), the
  nice side effect is if the term doesn't exist it creates it for you!
- *Spreadsheet* - Personally I created a Google Docs Spreadsheet, any type
  will do.  This spreadsheet has every field you want to map to fields
  in your content type.

**"More Better"**
Currently I am on the hunt for a simple backend UI way to do this, but this is what I've settled on for now.  I just couldn't imagine hand entering hundreds of nodes, page submit after page submit!  I will post back if I figure another way to do it.  Good luck!

Comment: This might do better in the Drupal Stack Exchange site? No?

Answer (score -1):

I have just started with
https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews
which enables the creation of views where all the fields are editable, including when no data exists in the related entity. At the first url is also documentation.

There a screencast which shows more
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_D4z4Bw6iw

Comment: While the links you provided may answer the question it is best to put the essential parts of your solution directly in your Stack Overflow answer in case those links expire in the future.